# How to get a PCIE device's link speed on Windows 7/8 programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, pci-e

On Windows 8 when I right click on a PCIE device in Device Manager, in the Details tab, under property "PCI current link speed" I can read the PCIe link speed. The same can be done for the PCIe link width.

I'd like to access this information programmatically in a C# application. How do I do that? through WMI?
And will the same work on Windows 7?

Comment: I'm new to WMI, so not sure where to start.

Comment: Start reading books / online resources. Search Google.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this kicks you a little:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace PCIeSpeedExample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2", "select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter");
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------------- Adapter ----------------");
            foreach (PropertyData pd in obj.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pd.Name, pd.Value);
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```